# Entity framework join table against a query

Tags: sql, entity-framework, join

I am using Entity Framework 6.1.1 and I have a query that joins a table against another select statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE Field = 123) AS T2 ON T1.Field = T2.Field
```

Is it possible to write something like this using Entity Framework's query syntax?

Answer (score 0):

```
from t1 in Table1
join t2 in Table2.Where(t => t.Field == 123) on t1.Field equals t2.Field into t2j
select new {
    T1 = t1,
    T2 = t2j.DefaultIfEmpty(),
}
```

You can filter `Table2` before the join and then use the group join + `DefaultIfEmpty` from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx:

> You can use LINQ to perform a left outer join by calling the [DefaultIfEmpty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.defaultifempty.aspx) method on the results of a group join.